# I need solution for this error "LateInitializationError: Field '_email@25051279' has already been initialized."

Tags: flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

the compiler tells me that error is here

```dart
late final TextEditingController _email;
 late final TextEditingController _password;
```

that is the debug-console

```
The following LateError was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
LateInitializationError: Field '_email@598051279' has already been initialized.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      LateError._throwFieldAlreadyInitialized (dart:_internal-patch/internal_patch.dart:201:5)
#1      _LoginViewState._email=
package:learn_flutter_37_hours/views/login.dart:16
#2      _LoginViewState.dispose
package:learn_flutter_37_hours/views/login.dart:21
#3      StatefulElement.unmount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4983
```

Comment: Where is the code that the TextEditingController _email is attached do?

Comment: Please show an better snippet of your code!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this because you reposted the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72174268/