# I want to solve this error please "LateInitializationError: Field '_email@598051279' has already been initialized."

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error while running my application

> LateInitializationError: Field '_email@598051279' has already been
> initialized.

*How can i fix this problem?*

this my code divided in two parts:

```dart
  
class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Login')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _email,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _password,
          ),
```

this is the second part

```
          Center(
            child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final email = _email.text;
                  final password = _password.text;
                  try {
                    final userCredintials =
                        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: email,
                      password: password,
                    );
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      notesRoute,
                      (route) => false,
                    );
                  } 
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is depug-console

```
LateInitializationError: Field '_email@49051279' has already been initialized.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      LateError._throwFieldAlreadyInitialized (dart:_internal-patch/internal_patch.dart:201:5)
#1      _LoginViewState._email=
package:learn_flutter_37_hours/views/login.dart:14
#2      _LoginViewState.dispose
```

Comment: check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401385/lateinitializationerror-field-data-has-not-been-initialized-got-error]

Answer (score 0):

In the `dispose()` method you are setting again the values of `_email` and `_password`:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Since both variables are `final`, you can only set their value once, as you do in `initState`. In fact you should dispose these controllers in the `dispose()` method and not set them again. Try this:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Your dispose function should no be like that. You need to replace it with the following code

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```